# Método / Função que "pare aplicação somente se o usuário pressionar uma tecla" em C#

Tags: c#, .net, lógica, revisão-de-código, console-application

Olá, eu estou praticando minha logica de programação no desenvolvimento de um app cronometro em C#... ele está contado os segundos, minutos e horas, até ai OK... porém eu quero criar a opção de o usuário "Pausar" o cronometro, tentei usar o método **Console.ReadKey()** mas o problema é que ele interrompe minha aplicação (parando de contar os segundos e minutos) esperando uma entrada do usuário, adoraria se alguém me desse alguma dica!!

```
        static void Cronometro()
    {
        int tempo = 59;
        int minutos = 0;
        int horas = 0;
        int play = 0;
        int segundos = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("1 - iniciar ");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Sair ");
        play = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
        if(play == 1)
        {
            do
            {
                //Função clear para limpar o console para nao ficar imprimindo infinitamente
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("P - Pausar ");
                Console.WriteLine("S - Sair ");

                Console.WriteLine();
                segundos++;
                Console.WriteLine(segundos + " segundos");
                Console.WriteLine(minutos + " min");
                Console.WriteLine(horas + " horas");
                Console.WriteLine();

                    if (segundos == 59)
                    {
                        segundos = 0;
                        minutos++;
                    }
                    if (minutos == 59)
                    {
                        minutos = 0;
                        horas++;
                    }
                    //delay de 1s para a aplicação nao bugar, pois o time de leitura do codiog é mt rapido
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }       
            //aqui estou preso, pois a aplicação é interrompida a espera de uma interação com o usuario...
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.P);
            Console.WriteLine("PAUSADO");
        }
        else if(play == 2)
        {
            Menu();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez seja interessante você declarar um método por exemplo "Pause" fora do escopo "Cronometro" e declará-lo como público para que você possa chamar a função toda vez que durante a execução da estrutura condicional for receber um comando diferente do que está sendo sugerido pelo programa. Ex:

```
static void Pause()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cronômetro pausado. Digite uma opção: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Continuar a cronometragem.");
        Console.WriteLine("2 - Voltar ao menu inicial.");
        string pausar = string.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (pausar)
        {
            case 1: cronometrar; break;
            default: Menu(); break;    
        }    

    }

static void cronometrar()
    {
        Cronometro()
    }
 //E então dentro do seu código, declare uma estrutura condicional do tipo:
    if(play == 1 && cronometrar)
    {
        do
        {
            // continua o código de reprodução do crônometro.
        }      
    }
```

Comment: Lembrando que você deve sempre se atentar sempre ao escopo onde você está declarando, para que posso fazer o uso posteriormente dentro de outros escopos.